# Running multiple instances of an executable in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-container-service, azure-container-instances

I have an executable that will be running for the lifetime of a user session.

Each user will cause a new instance of the executable to run.

If I package the executable up in a container, can I run multiple instance of the executable in the same container, or would I start multiple instances of the container?

Is it possible to run multiple instances of the container?
Would this scale, is there a limit to the number of container instances, or the number of executable instances I can run in a container (looking at the 100-1000s of users)?

Background: *The application needs to be packaged as an exe as it dynamically creates and loads assemblies which are specific to the user, these need unloading when the task completes, the only way I know of to do this is to run in your own process or in a separate AppDomain (and AppDomains are not implemented in .Net Core).*

Comment: What do you mean by multiple instances and the executable?

Comment: An executable process (i.e. MyApp.exe), and I need to run one instance of the .exe per user.

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, all the instances are in the container groups, when you create a container group, then the number of instances cannot change anymore. There is no scale for the container group. And if you create one instance in the container group, you can run multiple processes and create multiple users in the instance. How many processes you can create depends on how many resources the instance has. You can get the details about it in [Quotas and limits for Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quotas).